# Overflow error in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm running the following, pretty simple query on `Amazon Redshift`:

```
SELECT member_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS days
FROM ads.fbs_modality_staging
WHERE member_id in (select memberid from auth.members)
group by member_id
```

But this is giving me the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT member_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS days
FROM ads.fbs_modality_staging
WHERE member_id IN (SELEC...

[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647)
Details: 
 -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Overflow (Integer valid range -2147483648 to 2147483647)
  code:      1207
  context:   Value: '2952163128494839000', Character: '8'
  query:     2748804
  location:  :0
  process:   query5_95_2748804 [pid=0]
  -----------------------------------------------;

Execution time: 2.11s
1 statement failed.
```

I checked and the table `members` doesn't have a `memberid` of '2952163128494839000'. I also tried to use `CONVERT` and `CAST` functions to convert the `memberid` to `integer` but I got the same error.

Why am I facing this error and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: If  `members` doesn't have an out of range `memberid`, then perhaps `modality_staging` has an out of range `member_id`.  You say you used CAST/CONVERT: on which column.  Did you cast `members.memberid` to the same type as `modality_staging.member_id`?

Comment: I used `convert` on both - `modality_staging.member_id` and `members.memberid`

Comment: Convert to what?  What type is `modality_staging.member_id`?  That's probably what you should be converting to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you have a problem with the member id comparison.  I find it highly unlikely that you have enough dates to overflow the `count(distinct)`.

Convert them to strings:

```
SELECT member_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT TO_CHAR(created_at,'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS days
FROM ads.fbs_modality_staging
WHERE cast(member_id as varchar(255)) in (select cast(memberid as varchar(255)) from auth.members)
group by member_id
```

Comment: That conversion to varchar worked. Thanks a lot :). I'm wondering why the convert to integer did not work.. would you have any ideas?

Comment: @Patthebug . . . Clearly because not all the values can be converted to an integer.  Integers have a well-defined range of acceptable values.